# Acentuando os nomes de uma coluna dataframe

Tags: r, string, acentuação

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
funcionarios <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              nome = c("Claudio Roberto",
                       "Regina Marinho","Weronica Souza","Rogerio Lemos","Claudio Araujo"),
             setor = c("RH", "Recepção", "Almoxarifado", "RH", "RH"))
```

```
funcionarios
             nome        setor
1 Claudio Roberto           RH
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH
5  Claudio Araujo           RH
```

Os nomes "Cláudio", "Werônica" e "Rogério" não estão devidamente acentuados.

Além disso, o sobrenome "Araújo" (de Cláudio) também carece de acento.

Tentei resolver com `str_replace()`:

Primeiro para Cláudio:

```
> funcionarios %>% 
+   mutate(nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Claudio",
+                                       replacement = "Cláudio"))
```

Observe que os dois Cláudio foram devidamente acentuados.

```
             nome        setor  nome_acentuado
1 Claudio Roberto           RH Cláudio Roberto
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção  Regina Marinho
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado  Weronica Souza
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH   Rogerio Lemos
5  Claudio Araujo           RH  Cláudio Araujo
```

Ocorre que ao tentar replicar essa lógica para os demais nomes, apenas a última alteração é considerada.

Por exemplo, ao tentar com Cláudio e Werônica:

```
> funcionarios %>% 
+   mutate(nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Claudio",
+                                       replacement = "Cláudio"),
+          nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Weronica",
+                                       replacement = "Werônica"))
```

Observe que os Cláudios perderam os acentos e apenas Werônica está acentuado:

```
             nome        setor  nome_acentuado
1 Claudio Roberto           RH Claudio Roberto
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção  Regina Marinho
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado  Werônica Souza
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH   Rogerio Lemos
5  Claudio Araujo           RH  Claudio Araujo
```

A mesma coisa, quando tento acentuar Rogério:

```
> funcionarios %>% 
+   mutate(nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Claudio",
+                                       replacement = "Cláudio"),
+          nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Weronica",
+                                       replacement = "Werônica"),
+          nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
+                                       pattern = "Rogerio",
+                                       replacement = "Rogério"))
```

Rogério agora está acentuado e os Cláudios e Werônica não estão mais.

```
             nome        setor  nome_acentuado
1 Claudio Roberto           RH Claudio Roberto
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção  Regina Marinho
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado  Weronica Souza
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH   Rogério Lemos
5  Claudio Araujo           RH  Claudio Araujo
```

E o que dizer então de Cláudio Araújo? Como acentuar ambas as palavras que estão na mesma string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é usar a função [`stringr::str_replace_all()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace).

Como aparece na documentação da função, pode criar um vector com o padrão para realizar a substituição

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pattern = c("Claudio" = "Cláudio",
            "Weronica" = "Werônica",
            "Rogerio" = "Rogério")
```

Depois utilizar esse vector na função para criar uma nova coluna:

```
df %>%
    mutate(nom2 = str_replace_all(nome, pattern))
```

Output

```
    nome        setor            nom2
1 Claudio Roberto           RH Cláudio Roberto
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção  Regina Marinho
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado  Werônica Souza
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH   Rogério Lemos
5  Claudio Araujo           RH  Cláudio Araujo
```

Dados:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(nome = c("Claudio Roberto", "Regina Marinho", 
"Weronica Souza", "Rogerio Lemos", "Claudio Araujo"), setor = c("RH", 
"Recepção", "Almoxarifado", "RH", "RH")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Não entendi porque o voto negativo na minha resposta. Há algum tipo de problema no código? Agradeço comentaŕios.

Comment: Creio que seja pq faltou uma explicação detalhada do código, destacando onde estava o problema, o que mudou no código, o que foi usado e porque, etc.... Você colocou apenas o texto _`Uma opção`_ e códigos, sem detalhes e isso pode ser julgado como baixa qualidade e por isso o `-1`. Tente editar sua resposta e colocar mais detalhes na sua explicação. Tente explicar como se a pessoa que fosse ler fosse sua mãe/pai/marido/esposa/etc... que não tem menor conhecimento de programação! :-)

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário! Vou considerar essas informações.

Comment: esse nao parece ser motivo para voto negativo. Percebo que no SO em portugues tem muito mais voto negativo do que SO em ingles. Esse eh um exemplo de uma otima solucao que deveria ter votos positivos.

Comment: @RuamPimentel onde você viu esses dados?

Comment: Ótima solução @Jose. Exatamente o que eu estava buscando. Obrigado

Comment: Aprecio sua busca por dados ao inves de achismo. Infelizmente, meu comentario foi baseado na minha experiencia da ultima semana. Tenho olhado o SO todo dia nessa ultima semana, e é raro ver votos negativos no SO em ingles, porém no SO portugues tem sempre no minimo 4 ou 5 questoes com voto negativos (nas questoes recente sobre `r`). Isso tem me entrigado, porém não pesquisei sobre quantidade real de votos pos vs neg.

Comment: Valeu @itamar! eu fiquei preocupado por talvez ter feito algum equívoco na respsosta, mas fico feliz por ter ajudado.

Comment: @Jose, o código está escrito de maneira correta e parece atender o problema do usuário. Com não votei na questão, apenas posso supor que a motivação dos negativos possam ter vindo de dois motivos: 1) Conforme se insiram novos nomes no DF será necessário modificar o programa então seria mais manutenível uma abordagem cujo a lista de nomes e substituições fossem armazenada externamente ao programa. 2) Para contornar o problema da escalada da lista de nomes poderia se criar um programa que apenas aplicasse as regras gramaticais, da língua portuguesa, de acentuação aos substantivos próprios.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques: muito obrigado pelo comentário! os pontos que menciona são abordagens bem interessantes a esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, percebi o equívoco:
A coluna que eu deveria ter passado para registrar os novos acentos era a coluna nova que foi gerada: `nome_acentuado`.

Dessa forma o código deveria ter sido:

```
funcionarios %>% 
  mutate(nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome,
                                      pattern = "Claudio",
                                      replacement = "Cláudio"),
         nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome_acentuado,
                                      pattern = "Weronica",
                                      replacement = "Werônica"),
         nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome_acentuado,
                                      pattern = "Rogerio",
                                      replacement = "Rogério"),
         nome_acentuado = str_replace(nome_acentuado,
                                      pattern = "Araujo",
                                      replacement = "Araújo"))
```

Agora sim.

Ficou resolvido inclusive o sobrenome "Araújo":

```
             nome        setor  nome_acentuado
1 Claudio Roberto           RH Cláudio Roberto
2  Regina Marinho     Recepção  Regina Marinho
3  Weronica Souza Almoxarifado  Werônica Souza
4   Rogerio Lemos           RH   Rogério Lemos
5  Claudio Araujo           RH  Cláudio Araújo
```

Mas, aproveitando o ensejo: há uma forma mais limpa que ficar reescrevendo `str_replace()`?